# Conversion of Matrix to Columns

Tags: r

Say you have

```
Name     August   September   October     November
Bob        5          4          3            2
George     3          2          2            4 
Gina       1          4          2            1
```

And you want to convert into 3 columns like so

```
Name     Month       Output
Bob      August        5
Bob      September     4
.....
```

I see how to do it in VBA through the following link : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2773-excel-convert-matrix-to-list.html

Unsure how to execute in R. All of the searching I've yielded want to simply split the matrix into vectors which isn't correct.

Comment: You can try to post your codes

Comment: This is a very common task in R see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe, say, `df` you can define its column names as a column in its own right by using `names`:

```
df$Month <- names(df)[2:5]
```